# How can I control rails/webrick debug logging in development mode?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm seeing extra debug output in my development log. I've set the log level to warn using `config.log_level = :warn` but the output still contains the following:

```html
[2017-07-05 12:10:18] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2017-07-05 12:10:18] INFO  ruby 2.3.0 (2015-12-25) [x86_64-darwin14]
[2017-07-05 12:10:18] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=92408 port=4000

D, [2017-07-05T12:10:31.462798 #92408] DEBUG -- : REQUEST: 
Remote Address: ::1
Request URL: http://localhost:4000/
Request Method: GET
REQUEST HEADERS: 
 Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
 Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch, br
 Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
 Connection: keep-alive
 Host: localhost:4000
 If-None-Match: W/"d441be749644a1deaff4d6dea825b5f3"
 Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
 User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36
 Version: HTTP/1.1
Request Body: 

D, [2017-07-05T12:10:31.499359 #92408] DEBUG -- : RESPONSE: 
Response Status: 304
Response Headers: 
 X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
 X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
 X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
 ETag: W/"d441be749644a1deaff4d6dea825b5f3"
 Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
 X-Request-Id: 465f9693-964e-4552-976e-316cd6455d1d
 X-Runtime: 0.036204
Response Body: #<Rack::BodyProxy:0x007fba29da0530>
```

Where is the extra DEBUG output coming from? I don't see this info in my older projects.

Answer (score 0):

**Edited to add other solutions:**

You need to edit `config/environments/development.rb` and add this line: `config.log_level = :warn`, but make sure you restart the server after you add the line, for the changes to be applied.

You could also have have a debug statement in your app or gems (for example monkey patching the log level without setting it back as it was, which is a bad practice).
Search for debug (case insensitive) in your code, do you find something similar to `<%= debug @article %>`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but I have already made that configuration setting and it did not eliminate the output.

Comment: Did you restart the server? Can you paste your development config file in your message (you can remove the parts that are not relevant if you wish).

Comment: Also, you probably have a debug statement in your app, what if you search for `debug` (case insensitive) what do you get, do you find something similar to `<%= debug @article %>`. What is your Rails version?

Comment: I tracked it down to the marco polo gem: https://github.com/arches/marco-polo/issues - not sure why that gem triggers debug output, but at least I don't see it anymore!

Comment: Glad to help, I think it was a monkey patching for the log level without setting it back as it was, which is a bad practice

Answer (score 0):

I love old Questions. Especially if they are actual.

Fast solution, if you don't want WEBrick to talk at all:

```
WEBrick::Config::HTTP[:AccessLog]=[] #in application.rb
```

or if you want to controll the output a little bit more

put this in your `boot.rb`

```
require "webrick"
module WEBrick
    class GenericServer
        alias :original_start :start
        def start
            if Rails.env.development?
                @config[:AccessLog]=[]
                # or put a Logger.new and so on
            end
            original_start
        end
    end
end
```

Silence.

This works with:

Rails 3.2.22.5, WEBrick 1.3.1, ruby 2.3.1

and (until)

Rails 7.0.4.3, WEBrick 1.8.1, ruby 3.2.2

**Explanation**:

WEBrick does not know anything about Rails, therefore you can't configure it the standard way (`application.rb`). So we have to use an early point to (monkey-) patch the generic server, to configure it our way. Originally the contents of `@config[:AccessLog]` is

```
[[#<IO:<STDERR>>, "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %s %b"], [#<IO:<STDERR>>, "%{Referer}i -> %U"]]
```

Where ever that comes from :)

The problem is, that at `boot.rb` it is hard to find the environment, to make the patch only in development. So we use `start`, and hook in to change the `@config` then we call the original one.

If you want to change the format:

You can assign a logger you like as long as it takes "<<" like

```
new_logger=Logger.new(STDOUT)
new_logger.formatter=proc do |severity, datetime, progname, msg|
    ...
end
def new_logger.<< (msg)
    info msg 
end

@config[:AccessLog]=[[new_logger, "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %s %b"]] #see AccessLog
```